# How use sprintf to output a floating point number lesser then 1 without a leading decimal place?

Tags: php, printf

I am trying to use sprintf to print a float number without pre-zero. The numbers are always less than 1

0.12345 => .12345

My attempt:

```
<?php
$string = sprintf('%0.6F',0.12345678);
```

I get "0.123457" but I need ".123457". I can do this with ltrim:

```
$string = ltrim(sprintf('%0.6F',0.12345678),'0');  //string(7) ".123457"
```

Is there a special format that can only be done with sprintf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to trim the zero before a decimal as any option with `sprintf()` and `float`.

**sprintf() fF**

> The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in
>   the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the
>   decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If
>   the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is
>   explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal
>   point appears, at least one digit appears before it.

↳ http://www-sbras.nsc.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/man-cgi?sprintf

As an alternative to `ltrim()` you could use `substr` perhaps:

```
substr(sprintf('%.6f', 0.12345678), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for another answer, but I have to accept the facts.